# read blocks despite that O_NONBLOCK set

Tags: c, posix

If I set `O_NONBLOCK` when `open` file, everything works OK. But `read` blocks when I set `O_NONBLOCK` via `fcntl`. What's wrong?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
                                                                
#include <stdio.h>

void
make_nonblock(size_t N, int in[N]) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    int flags = fcntl(in[i], F_GETFL);
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(in[i], F_SETFL, flags);
  }
}

extern size_t
read_data_and_count(size_t N, int in[N]) {
  make_nonblock(N, in);
  char buffer[4096];
  size_t total = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ssize_t current = 0;
    while ((current = read(in[i], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
      total += current;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int fds[1024];
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    fds[i - 1] = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
  }
  size_t result = read_data_and_count(argc - 1, fds);
  printf("Result: %ld\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you reading from?

Comment: @zwol from fifo

Comment: Named pipes are quirky and sometimes also buggy. Try using a normal (anonymous) pipe or a socket instead.  (However, what you are doing _should_ work, I think.  I don't see any obvious bugs in your code.)

Comment: You don't check for an error result in either of the calls to fcntl.  Next thing to do is make sure your calls aren't returning an error.

Comment: Because open is blocking then. Isn't it your problem? Are you sure you are blocking in read not in open? Opening a fifo in blocking mode waits until a writer comes in (idea is not let you try reading if there is no writer, no hope to succeed).